# Eclipse not showing fields for any objects when choosing metadata components

Tags: ide, eclipse

I'm trying to use Eclipse to create a new project. When I attempt to choose metadata components, I do not see any fields under the objects. When I expand the objects, all I see are workflows.

I've tried re-installing the Force.com IDE multiple times and it never seems to work.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Do you have to use Eclipse?  I'm not sure about your issue, but MavensMate is very good with Force.com http://mavensmate.com/

Comment: 1) identify your eclipse version + sandbox version; 2) edit your post to include a screen shot of how you are selecting metadata components.

Comment: I've tried using eclipse version 4.2 as well as 4.3. My sandbox version is Spring '14. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points to add a screenshot here.

Comment: Any more ideas on this? This limitation is making it impossible to use Eclipse.

Comment: 1) before doing the Component selection, did you try clicking the refresh schema button in the upper right of the dialog? 2) Please post your package.xml file contents into your original post

Comment: I did try the refresh button and it didn't fix the issue. However, the good news is that I finally fixed the problem this morning. To do this, I uninstalled all versions of Java on my machine, and deleted every Eclipse file, regardless of what folder it was in (since Eclipse writes to multiple locations). Then re-installed Java and Eclipse. Thank you to everyone for your ideas and help on this.

Comment: Charles -- great -- post your last comment as an Answer and then mark as a solution (1 day later)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem this morning. To do this, I uninstalled all versions of Java on my machine, and deleted every Eclipse file, regardless of what folder it was in (since Eclipse writes to multiple locations). Then re-installed Java and Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a workaround:

To retrieve objects along with your custom metadata, you have to manually add necessary objects to your Eclipse package.xml file. 
For example, to retrieve a custom object MyObject__c (with all fields, validation rules, record types etc), you should add:

```
<types>
    <members>MyObject__c</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```